# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'FirstPage' is defined

Tags: java, spring

I am very new to Spring Framework. I am using **NetBeans** for IDE. I followed couple of tutorials to learn it by myself. However, I am stuck in the middle and cannot proceed further. Let me breakdown my project here:

My **project folder** structure looks like this:

[image: Folder Structure Image]

There are two classes; the major one **MainApp.java** contains following code:

```
package com.myprojects.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context;
      context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:beans.xml");
      FirstPage obj;
      obj = (FirstPage) context.getBean("firstPage");
      obj.getMessage();     
      
   }
}
```

Second class file **FirstPage.java** looks like this:

```
package com.myprojects.spring;

public class FirstPage {
    
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }
   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
    
}
```

The **beans.xml** file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.xsd
">
    <bean id = "firstPage" class = "com.myprojects.spring.FirstPage">
      <property name = "message" value = "Hello World!"/>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

Now, the **error** I am getting is like below:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'firstPage' is defined

I know I have been doing some silly mistake here.
Thank you in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost similar problem have been discussed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957419/2815219). I think your program is unable to locate `beans.xml`.

Try doing this:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/beans.xml");
```

EDIT:

This new error `XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException` means that your schema is not valid. Try changing your schema as described in one of these answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21525719/2815219
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25782515/2815219
3. [Spring configuration XML schema: with or without version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20894695/2815219)

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

       <bean id = "firstPage" class = "com.myprojects.spring.FirstPage">
         <property name = "message" value = "Hello World!"/>
       </bean> 
   </beans>
   ```

Comment: I just tried that but ended up in another path error:
`.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/beans.xml] is invalid`

Comment: @SajhaParty that solves the answer this question is addressing. Now your spring is actually able to find `beans.xml`. It's another issue that it's not able to parse that XML.

Comment: @SajhaParty I've updated my answer to solve `XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException XML document ... invalid` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Put beans.xml to outside Meta-inf ,

or use new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/beans.xml");

And http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.xsd

should change to

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.0.xsd , as spring's xsd filenames don't contain "RELEASE".

The xsd files are in org.springframework.beans.factory.xml package in spring-beans.jar, see if the xsd file is in that package.

Answer (score 0):

According to the directory structure you posted it is very likely that `src/main/resources` is on your classpath. If you like to reference your spring context file `beans.xml` you have to specify it relative to the folders on your classpath. Hence you should try:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/META-INF/beans.xml");
```

Besides: the notation `classpath*:beans.xml` means you want to read in all context files having a name of `beans.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing following two things solved my issue.

1) There was an incorrect **beans.xml** path. I changed that to `context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/beans.xml");`.

2) Also, there was an invalid **xsi:schemaLocation** attribute value. I changed that attribute's value to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd`.

Thank you all for your help.